# mysql.sock missing: php connection works but cant connect from terminal

Tags: mysql

When I try to run mysql from the command line I get the following:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

interestingly the php scripts that connect to mysql in /var/www appear to be connecting just fine and when I stop MySQL these scripts can no longer connect as expected. However when I start mysql I continue to get the missing .sock error from the command line while my php scripts once again are connected to the database they are supposed to.

I have tried restarting mysql in various ways (restarting, starting then stopping, sudo pkill mysql) and still no luck. The only sock file on my system is /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock; but, without being sure that this is the cause of the command line error I dont want to haphazardly make symbolic links in my /tmp directory.

How can I resolve the issue of connecting to mysql via the command line? some suggestions I have read recommend reinstalling MySQL which I don't want to do considering my php connection is working.

Comment: Either change the path of socket file in my.cnf file or you may use --host option while connecting. We can connect MySQL using with UDP which is socket or TCP which involves providing either --host=localhost or IP or you can also use --protocol=TCP option.

Comment: UDP -> Unix Socket. You could create a `~/.my.cnf` with a `[client]\nsocket=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Comment: Or you can list all the current listening sockets (network and FS) by `ss -l | grep mysql` on the most linux systems.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check your MySQL config file `my.cnf` and make sure it contains socket parameter

```
[client]
socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

if those parameters not presented then you need to add them and start MySQL service.

after that you need to change MySQL folder permission sudo `chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/` and make sure it is owned by MySQL user.

finally start MySQL service.

Note: you need to make sure ports are opened for MySQL inside firewall

Comment: to be precise I used danblack's comment from above but I really appreciate the help!